# Sharepoint 2013 IE shows different URL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, internet-explorer, angularjs, firefox

When I open my SP with Internet Explorer and navigate through my navigation, IE always shows an other URL as the link has (always add the link with a # at the end of the URL) - Please see picture below:

[image]

But when I open the same site with Firefox the URL don't change:

[image]

Anybody know, how to configure that IE is also showing the right URL ?

My Problem is that under the URL, which IE shows, my Jquery and Angular Applications did not working - With Firefox the application runs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell you what part of SP decides when you should browse by navigating between pages, or when the `start.aspx` is used, but once `start.aspx` is used it uses the hash to store the location of where you are, in case you copy it and link a colleague.

You can find some information in this blog post:

http://www.hezser.de/blog/2012/08/18/what-is-the-_layouts15start-aspx-in-sharepoint-2013/

According to the comments on the article, you can deactivate the site feature `Minimal Download Strategy` and that should get rid of you being redirected to the `start.aspx` file when you navigate around your site.

It will obviously increase load time, since there will be more overhead when loading the full site between pages. It might not be a big problem, but keep that in mind.

Comment: Perfect - Deactivate Minimal Download Strategy and the application runs fine. Thanks for that.